# Send windows notification after a predefined time a particular website www.xyz.com loads in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Currently I am working on a Chrome extension which will give a notification on my desktop 120 sec. after a particular website (say [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com)) is loaded in any tab of Chrome. What do I need to do for it with background.js and manifest.JSON? I am ready with the design of notification, the message, etc. But it is delivered at an interval of 120 sec using chrome.alarms API. It does not consider which web page is loaded or anything of that sort. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind
is to store the tabId whose url has changed to [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com) into an array.

Then inside the onUpdate event handler check if this tabId already exists in that array.
If it does not exist then add it to the array and schedule an alarm (remember to give the alarm a unique name for example by adding the tabId itself as a suffix)
If the tabId already exists in the array, do nothing.

If you close the tab before the alarm is triggered, however, you must also delete the alarm related to the tabId (chrome.alarms.clear)
By closing the tab, you could also delete the element in the corresponding array so as not to enlarge it too much.
To do these last two things you need to make use of events:

chrome.windows.onRemoved and chrome.tabs.onRemoved

The above if you are using a persistent background script.

If not, you need to store the array in chrome.storage.local

Comment: Basically there is an array you can use that increases when you create an alarm and empties when the alarm is fired (as long as automatic repetition is not set).
With  chrome.alarms.getAll  you can query the active alarms and get an array of alarms.
Note that all chrome.alarms API are all asynchronous.
If you have problems with them use a standard array as I suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

You have to request "tabs" and "alarms" permissions on manifest.json

Then in your background script define a event handler for chrome.tabs.onUpdate
which checks the url (changed or inserted in any tabs) for [www.xyz.com](http://www.xyz.com).
If the update url matchs this pattern then you have to set a two-minute alarm from now.

Something like this:

```
function alarm_manager(alarm) {
    if (alarm.name.startsWith('a_name_for_your_alarm')) {
        console.log('Wake up, the alarm has set')
/* you can use here also an alert or a notification */
    }
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(alarm_manager);

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (changeInfo?.status == "complete") {
        if (tab.url.includes("www.xyx.com"))
            chrome.alarms.create('a_name_for_your_alarm' + '_' + tabId, { delayInMinutes: 2 });
        else
            chrome.alarms.clear('a_name_for_your_alarm' + '_' + tabId);
    }
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener((tabId, removeInfo) => {
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, tab => {
        if (tab.url.includes("www.xyx.com"))
            chrome.alarms.clear('a_name_for_your_alarm' + '_' + tabId);
    })
});
```

You have not specified if this alarm have to be scheduled every time navigation meets that web site or just once.

Adapt the code accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the help, Robbi!  For a given tab in chrome, the notification should be delivered only once, and for each tab that has webpage www.xyz.com, the notification must be delivered separately 120 sec. after the webpage is loaded in that tab. E.g., if in tab 1 and tab 2, the www.xyz.com is loaded at 5:02 pm and 6:00 pm respectively, then two separate desktop notifications will be sent at 5: 04 and 6:02. Notification for a tab should not be sent if the tab is closed within 120 sec. after loading.

Comment: This works very well, except that it gives notification even if I close the tab within 2 minutes, or if I load some other webpage in the same tab. I want to add a condition that will check if the webpage 'www.xyz.com' is still loaded when the notification is delivered. How do I do that?

Comment: Please note I've changed the code a bit.
In practice, when I change the tab url I'm going to delete the respective alarm even if it does not exist (it should not generate any error).
The thing is not very different when instead I go to close the tab
I can't access the tab url directly from the onRemove event handler, so I have to query the tab first with that tabId. But when you'll close the (last \ the only) window it won't work. When you open back the browser all already scheduled alarms will start unless you study a system that prevents it.

Comment: Works perfect! An additional comment: Use chrome.notifications.clear('notification_name') after creating it. I found that if we do not do so, subsequent notifications will be suppressed.

Comment: The time after which notification appears is not always 2 minutes. It is sometimes 2 minutes, sometimes 2:30, sometimes 2:45. What could be the reason and how to rectify it? Can we use any function other than alarm?

Comment: Can setInterval be incorporated?

Comment: These alarms are not from a swiss clock. They can have some delay. Check the official documentation for details.
Each time the tab meets the URL www.xyz.com, the corresponding alarm (with tabId in the suffix) is rescheduled.
If the delay you're talking is due to the above rescheduleding you have to prevent this behaviour by checking first if that alarm already exists.
setTimeout could be a valid alternative only if you are not developing a mv3 extention.